# HttpClient.PostAsync() seemingly falls into a black hole

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, dotnet-httpclient

I'm currently in the middle of trying to get my MVC application to send JSON to a web API, which once the API finishes processing the given data, returns a response (in this case a session ID).

I've currently hit a brick wall in waiting for the response from the API, while the API does everything it should, it sends back a JSON string, then in my main application, instead of moving on and checking for the contents of the response, it just doesn't hit any of my break points after a response has been sent from the API.

This is the function that I'm having an issue with:

```
    public static async Task<object> loginAsync(string p_sApiActionUrl, string p_ApiAuth, string p_sPostContent)
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiUrl"]);

                var httpResponse = await httpClient.PostAsync(p_sApiActionUrl, new StringContent(p_sPostContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

                if (httpResponse.Content != null) [!!!BREAKPOINT!!!]
                {
                    // Error Here
                    var responseContent = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                }
                else
                {
                    string s = "test";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                string error = e.Message;
            }
        }

        return "";
    }
```

Excuse the code after the [!!!BREAKPOINT!!!] flag, I'm still writing it. So if I put a breakpoint where indicated (and even breakpoints after this), it doesn't error or throw an exception, it instead just refreshes the form and you're able to re-submit the data as before...

What's happening? Am I missing something? All I'm wanting to do is fetch the JSON response from this API call and serialize it.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Don't swallow exceptions.

Comment: @SLaks - I don't intend on doing, at the moment the catch there was to see if I could find out why/if it was failing, but it doesn't even hit that exception.

Comment: You're almost certainly calling `Wait` or `Result` on a task further up your call stack. This can [easily cause deadlocks](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), as I explain on my blog.